# How to avoid this annoying autocomplete in visual studio code

Tags: python, ide, visual-studio-code

When I type `import tensorflow as tf` it automatically complete `tf` to `try/finally` block when I press the enter key, which is annoying and not intelligent at all, how to avoid this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are snippet suggestions. Try setting:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "none"
```

to disable them.

Comment: It would be nice if this could be disabled just during `import ... as ...` statements. It's not just snippets, the autocomplete is generally wrong and useless during importing, since you're trying to make a custom reference to a module, and the autocomplete won't be able to guess what you want to call it. In my example, when I try to `import numpy as np`, the suggestions are `NotImplemented` and `NotImplementedError` instead of `np`, which is equally ridiculous. Any idea if this is a VSCode issue or more to do with the Python extension? Would be good to bring this to the devs attention.

Comment: It does not work at all, I disabled it and it still show suggestion, then on space button key press it autocompletes.. It is amazing how annoying this feature became.

Comment: This only disables snippet suggestions. Other suggestions will still be shown

Answer (score 5):

Search your workspace settings for Editor: Accept Suggestion On Enter and set it to Off. Now when you type `import numpy as np` you will see `numpy` as the suggested completion. If you hit tab, VSC will use the suggestion, but if you hit Enter it will not.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and solved it by disabling "accept suggestions on enter" in settings.

This way, the suggestion will still come up but you need to use the tab key to accept the suggestion.

`"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": false`